# Contradiction between the results of calculation and the theoretical analysis of Stark effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, atoms, quantum-states

@Emilio Pisanty, in your explanation of [the Stark effect on the furst excited state of Hydrogen](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64480/stark-effect-on-the-1st-excited-state-of-hydrogen/536411#536411), the electron cloud obtained by theoretical analysis shows that [image] when the electric field is along the **-z** axis, the $200-210$ state has a higher energy, although [image] the calculation result shows that when electric field is along the **z** axis, the 200-210 state has a higher energy. I do not understand the reason for this contradiction.

Comment: Recall that $U_{dipole} = -\vec{p} \cdot \vec{E}$ (with a suitable definition of where U is zero).

Comment: Yeah, so for 200-210state, if you look at the rightside of figure1, the electric dipole is pointting upwards, if the electric field is also pointting up wards then the perterbation energy is negative, but actually it is positive according the figure2

Comment: The electric field is pointing downward, which makes the  potential energy positive, where as in the left image it is negative

Comment: Here is the problem, when I study in my textbook, it first assume that the electricfield is along +z axis, then get the fig2 result.